# Avoiding boolean parameters in class initialization for checksum object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a class to store checksums of mostly remote files and then confirm that those checksums have or haven't changed after certain operations.

I originally created something rather simple, which selected whether the remote host was using posix or windows paths as a boolean switch.

```
from pathlib import Path, PurePosixPath, PureWindowsPath

class CheckFileNonCohesive(CheckFile):
    __slots__ = ['checksum', 'filepath', 'path']
    def __init__(self, checksum: str, filepath: str, *, windows: bool=False, posix: bool=False):
        if windows and posix:
            raise ValueError("windows and posix can't both be True")
        if windows:
            self.path = PureWindowsPath
        elif posix:
            self.path = PurePosixPath
        else:
            path = Path
        self.checksum = str(checksum)
        self.filepath = self.path(str(filepath))
```

However, I'm not sure how cohesive this class was. It felt strange to pass in windows or posix as an init param. I then split it into three classes. I believe this if following general best practices, but I'm not sure if the change was worth it or if it's overkill for this use case. Here is the final classes for review:

```
from pathlib import Path, PurePosixPath, PureWindowsPath
import typing

PathTypes = typing.Union[Path, PureWindowsPath, PurePosixPath]


def driveless_str(path: PathTypes):
    if path.drive:
        return str(path).replace(path.drive, "", 1)
    return str(path)


class CheckFile:
    """A representation of a point in time of a file with a full path and checksum

    For information on path naming conventions see PATH_NAMING.md
    """
    __slots__ = 'checksum', 'filepath'
    path = Path

    def __init__(self, checksum: str, filepath: str):
        """
        :param checksum: Checksum of the file, int's can be passed in, but will be converted to strings
        :param filepath: Full absolute filepath
           note: as CheckFiles are often on remote files the absolute path without redirects is safest as pathlib is
                 unlikely to be able to follow
        """
        self.checksum = str(checksum)
        self.filepath = self.path(str(filepath))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.filepath == other.filepath and self.checksum == other.checksum

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.checksum, self.filepath, self.path))

    @property
    def basename(self) -> str:
        return self.path(self.filepath).name

    def equal_by_basename(self, other: 'CheckFile') -> bool:
        return self.checksum == other.checksum and self.basename == other.basename

    def equal_with_dirname(self, other: 'CheckFile', dirname: str) -> bool:
        return self.checksum == other.checksum and self.path(dirname + self.basename) == other.path(other.filepath)

    def not_equal_with_dirname(self, other: 'CheckFile', dirname: str) -> bool:
        return self.checksum != other.checksum and self.path(dirname + self.basename) == other.path(other.filepath)

    def equal_with_mountpoint(self, other: 'CheckFile', mountpoint: str) -> bool:
        mounted_filepath = self.prepend_path(mountpoint, self.filepath)
        return self.checksum == other.checksum and mounted_filepath == other.filepath

    def _prepend_path_to_str(self, prepend: str, filepath: PathTypes) -> str:
        prepend_path = self.path(prepend)
        if prepend_path.drive or filepath.drive:
            return prepend_path.drive + driveless_str(prepend_path) + driveless_str(filepath)
        return prepend + str(filepath)

    def prepend_path(self, prepend: str, filepath: PathTypes) -> PathTypes:
        return self.path(self._prepend_path_to_str(prepend, filepath))


class PosixCheckFile(CheckFile):
    __slots__ = ()
    path = PurePosixPath

    def _prepend_path_to_str(self, prepend: str, filepath: PathTypes) -> str:
        return prepend + str(filepath)


class WindowsCheckFile(CheckFile):
    __slots__ = ()
    path = PureWindowsPath
```

I think this is a lot nicer, but I'm sure there is still room for improvement. One of the things worth considering is if I for some reason need a factory class that basically returns to the original simple use case I could do so with a factory.

```
class CFFactory:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        windows = kwargs.pop('windows', None)
        posix = kwargs.pop('posix', None)

        if windows and posix:
            raise ValueError("windows and posix can't both be True")
        if windows:
            return type.__call__(WindowsCheckFile, *args, **kwargs)
        if posix:
            return type.__call__(PosixCheckFile, *args, **kwargs)
        return type.__call__(CheckFile, *args, **kwargs)
```

However, if I find that I am using this factory a lot was it not better to simply use something more like the initial implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach feels cleaner as a user can choose to use

```
file_checker = module.WindowsCheckFile(...)
```

directly. And the factory can still be used if the decision need to be taken at runtime.

However, there are a few things bothering me about this factory. For starter, there is no need to use a class: a simple function will do. Second, instead of `pop`ing default values, you can insert them in the signature. Lastly `type.__call__` is really off here, you can call the class directly:

```
def CheckFileFactory(*args, windows=None, posix=None, **kwargs):
    if windows and posix:
        raise ValueError("windows and posix can't both be True")
    if windows:
        return WindowsCheckFile(*args, **kwargs)
    if posix:
        return PosixCheckFile(*args, **kwargs)
    return CheckFile(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Changing it to a function definitely makes it a lot cleaner!

I wouldn't have been able to return an initialized object from `__new__` if it was a class. What's wrong with `type.__call__`? How else would you propose doing it?

Comment: @Brian [`type.__call__(ClassName, ...)` is just a fancy and error-prone way to write `ClassName(...)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178162/call-method-of-type-class). It is unclear at best for the unaware reader and would create wrong results whenever metaclasses comes to play.